# How to compute the limit with sinx

Tags: limits

I came across this exercise, which leads to computing the limit of  $$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin x\ln(x+\sin x)\right)$$

When using the Taylor expansion, how can one be able to tell should $\sin x$ be replaced with $x$ or $x-{1 \over6}x^3$ just by looking at it, or should I try each of them?

This might seem to be a easy problem, but I really need some help

Comment: what Kind of rules can you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply and divide by $x$:

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot x\ln(x + \sin(x))$$

Use the known limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\ln(\alpha x) = 0 ~~~~~~~ \alpha \in\mathbb{R}$$

And then you will find the final limit is

$$\boxed{\color{red}{e^0 = 1}}$$

P.s.

$\ln(x + \sin(x)) \approx \ln(2x)$ as $x\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

It suffices use a first order approximation

- $\sin x \sim x$

and recall that

- $x\log x\to 0$